# javascript check to see if value matches object

Tags: javascript, object

I have a javascript object

```
var obj = {
    "0" : "apple",
    "1" : "pear",
    "2" : "orange"
}
```

I want to check if 'orange' is in obj.

Is there a built in function that does this? Or should I iterate over each value of obj?

Thanks.

Comment: If performance is an issue, keep a parallel object current that looks like `{"apple": true, "pear": true, "orange": true}`. Then you can do a very speedy `"apple" in parallelObj` to do existence checks.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You'll have to iterate:

```
for (var k in obj) {
  if (!obj.hasOwnProperty(k)) continue;
  if (obj[k] === "orange") {
    /* yaay! an orange! */
  }
}
```

Now that "hasOwnProperty" test in there is to make sure you don't stumble over properties inherited from the prototype. That *might* not be desirable in some cases, and really it's one of the things you kind-of need to understand in order to know for sure whether you do or don't want to make that test. Properties that you pick up from an object's prototype can sometimes be things dropped there by various libraries.  (I think the ES5 standard provides for ways to control whether such properties are "iterable", but in the real world there's still IE7.)

Comment: Although, all the cool kids are testing with `Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(obj, k)`.

Comment: Yes, good point @sdleihssirhc - that's definitely a good idea if there's concern that objects might be "polluted" somehow :-)

Answer (score 2):

There is no built in function to do this, you'd have to check each property.

Also by the looks of your object, it should be an array instead of an object. If that was the case it would be slightly easier to iterate through the values and be marginally more efficient.

```
var arr = ['apple','pear','orange'];
function inArray(inVal){
    for( var i=0, len=arr.length; i < len; i++){
        if (arr[i] == inVal) return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function has(obj, value) {
  for(var id in obj) {
    if(obj[id] == value) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}

if(has(obj, "orange")) { /* ... */ }
```

Comment: +1, but with the caveat that this doesn't do the prototype check. If you might be checking objects that have prototypes, change `obj[id] == value` to `obj.hasOwnProperty(id) && obj[id] == value`. Also consider using `===` for strict equality instead of `==` for loose equality.

Answer (score 0):

You might wanna look at [jQuery.inArray](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/). Think it works for objects aswell.

Comment: Thanks for the suggest, unfortunately I tried it and it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

```
const TESTobj = ( Obj, Value ) => {
    let IsBool = 0;
    Object.values(Obj).forEach((val) => { if(val===Value){ IsBool++; }; });
    if( IsBool ){ return true; } else{ return false; };
};

var obj = { "0": "apple", "1": "pear", "2": "orange" };

console.log( TESTobj( obj, `orange` ) );
// return true;

console.log( TESTobj( obj, `peach` ) );
// return false;
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).